# Rails: routes for static resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have css/html content with js for script paths and css for stylesheets, but my scripts are in javascript files and styles in stylesheets paths.

how do i configure routes.rb to map all img requests to images folder, js to javascripts folder and css requests to stylesheets folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails, and therefore the routes.rb file is not involved with serving static assets. In development a rack middleware exists that serves the file if it exists in your projects /public directory. So when a request comes in for /images/foo.png, it will look in public/images/ for foo.png and serve it up if it exists.

If you are using the Rails view helpers for static assets, then you will already have the proper output URLs that will map to public/images, public/stylesheets and public/javascripts